# Is their a way to split a single 2d array into multiple 1d arrays of various shapes using the 1st column as an index?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I'm trying to split a 2d numpy array into multiple 1d arrays of the 2nd column using the first column as an index. the 2d array is very large (2,100000)

basically i have an array that looks like this (just a lot larger):

```
[[1,a]
 [1,a2]
 [1,a3]
  ....
 [100,b]
 [100,b2]]
```

I want to split it into two arrays that look like

```
[a,a2,a3]
```

and

```
[b,b2]
```

I'm not even sure on where to start or search and would greatly appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `itertools.groupby`. You need to specify a `key` function, which specifies how to group the elements in your nested `list` (in this case, by the first element). In this case, we can use `itemgetter`.

Per your requirements, you only want each group to contain the second element of the original data, so `itemgetter` can help there too.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

data = [[1, 'a'],
        [1, 'b'],
        [1, 'c'],
        [2, 'a'],
        [2, 'b'],
        [3, 'c']]

result = {key: list(map(itemgetter(1), group)) for key, group in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(0))}

print(result)
```

Output:

```
{1: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 2: ['a', 'b'], 3: ['c']}
```

Note that you should sort the input nested `list` first if the keys are not already in order, otherwise they will be split into multiple groups with the same key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.flatnonzero` (or `np.nonzero` or `np.where`) and `np.diff` to find the block boundaries and then split using `np.split`:

```
# create example
x = np.c_[np.repeat(*sum(np.ogrid[:2, 1:4])), 1:10]
x
# array([[1, 1],
#        [1, 2],
#        [2, 3],
#        [2, 4],
#        [2, 5],
#        [3, 6],
#        [3, 7],
#        [3, 8],
#        [3, 9]])
np.split(x[:, 1], np.flatnonzero(np.diff(x[:, 0])) + 1)
# [array([1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([6, 7, 8, 9])]
```